# Convergence of two-sided series implies convergence of one-sided series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I was reading Georgi Shilov's *Elementary Real and Complex Analysis*. In section 6.48 (p.209), he proves that on $\mathbb R^n$, if a two-sided series $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty a_k$ converges, i.e. if there is a vector $s\in\mathbb R^n$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an integer $N>0$ that makes $\left\|s-\sum_{k=-p}^qa_k\right\|<\epsilon$ for any $p,q\ge N$, then the one-sided series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{-k}$ also converge.

His proof makes use of Cauchy sequence. Is it possible to infer the convergences of the one-sided series without using the completeness of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: If one of the one-sided series diverges then so does the two-sided one, quite by definition. Without the completeness it doesn't really make sense, take the one-sided series converging to $\pi$ and $-\pi$, thus not int $\mathbb{Q}$, but $\sum_k a_k$ converges to $0 \in \mathbb{Q}$ (the two one-sided series are Cauchy and they do not converge in $\mathbb{Q}$)

Comment: @reuns You're right! Would you please turn your comment into an answer? I'll gladly accept it.